# PrimeNG Tree expanded

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

I am trying to set selected items in PrimeNG Tree.

**HTML**

```
<p-tree  id="selectedProducts" *ngIf="selectedCustomer != null"
[value]="tree" selectionMode="checkbox"
[(selection)]="selectedProducts"
(click)="fileterProducts()"></p-tree>
```

**TS**

```
selectedProducts: TreeNode[] = [];
filteredProducts: number[] = [];
tree: TreeNode[] = [];

selectCustomer(customerId: number){
this.selectedCustomer = this.selectedCustomers.find(r => r.Name == this.userForm.value.Customers[0]);
console.log("Customer Products ");
console.log(this.selectedCustomer.selectedProducts);


this.selectedProducts = this.selectedCustomer.selectedProducts;

for ( let product of this.selectedProducts ) {
  product.expanded = true;
  this.expandChildren(product);
  console.log('Product : ');
  console.log(product);
}
```

and I made all the nodes expanded, but it doesn't appear selected.

Comment: Can you share your component TS code please ?

Comment: I added the code above

Comment: *but it doesn't appear selected* Do you mean checkboxes are not checked or leaves are not expanded ? Can you create a StackBlitz please ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have all nodes expanded and selected, including all children to any depth?

Then you need to call `expandChildren` recursively and add children to `[(selection)]` too, because it is working only with references.